# Утечка памяти и высокая загруженность CPU, С++

Tags: c++, методы, утечка-памяти, cpu

У меня есть процедурный генератор английских слов, я запустил его в такой форме, чтобы проверить на утечку памяти:

```
word word; // этот объект хранит в себе слово, транскрипцию и сид.

generator assembler;

int i = 0; 

do { assembler (word, ++i); } while (true); // (word &word, int seed);
```

Он бесконечно генерирует слова в объект word, замещая старые данные.

В диспетчере задач я обнаружил утечку памяти (~33 кб/c) и довольно высокую загруженность CPU (~16%; AMD FX-8320, 8-и ядерный).

Везде, где была выделена динамическая память, использовался delete.

Может ли утекать память от таких методов?

```
int foo (std::vector<std::wstring> exceptions)
{
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Или нужно делать так?

```
int foo (std::vector<std::wstring> exceptions)
{
    ...

    delete[] exceptions;
    return 0;
}
```

Ещё у меня практически все методы возвращают 0 в никуда.

```
int foo () { return 0; }

foo (); // т.е. значение, возвращаемое функцией, никуда не записывается
```

А вот по поводу высокой загрузки CPU предположений нет.

- Из-за чего утекает оперативная память?
- Что вызывает повышенную загрузку CPU?

Comment: используйте `valgrind` для обнаружения утечек памяти. И в с++ принята концепции RAII - лучше используйте выделение в конструкторе, а удаление в деструкторе.

Comment: Вы бы лучше не использовали `new` и `delete` без крайней необходимости. 2018 год на дворе, у нас давно есть стандартные контейнеры и умные указатели, в 99% случаев их достаточно... С ними получить утечку намного сложнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызывать `delete[]` явно имеет смысл только для того, что было создано явно же через `new[]`. Класс `std::vector` сам управляет памятью, поэтому никакие `delete` к нему применять нельзя. Более того `delete`, `delete[]` требуют операнда типа указатель, т.е. предложенный вариант `delete[] exceptions;` выглядит вовсе абсурдным.

Для того чтобы выявлять утечки памяти следует использовать специализованные программы или встроенные в IDE средства. Гуглить по "memory leaks detector". Опираться на информацию обычного диспетчера задач ОС недостаточно.

Ну, а про 16% это скорее всего говорит о том, что полностью загружено одно ядро вашего процессора из-за цикла `do/while` без каких-либо пауз (`sleep`). Хотя при 8 ядрах скорее должно быть 12.5%.

Comment: Нет, конкретно сама программа нагружает до 16%, а не на ~12%.

Comment: @Mournehowl это скорее всего специфика подсчёта ОС, хотя может у Вас ещё есть потоки в программе - один отъедает 12.5%, а ещё 3.5% другой.

Comment: Нет, программа работает в одном потоке.

Answer (score 4):

У Вас в цикле выполняется условие:

```
do { assembler (word, ++i); } while (true); // (word &word, int seed);
```

Выполняется на столько быстро, на сколько это возможно используя все ресурсы одного ядра, вот отсюда и нагрузка процессора ~16% (100% / 8 ядер).

По поводу утечек в диспетчере задач: это не самый лучший способ проверять на утечки памяти, для этого нужно использовать такие инструменты как Visual Leak Detector (для MSVC) или аналоги

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` сам управляет памятью для своих внутренних элементов и в случае `std::vector<std::wstring>` все необходимые операции освобождения памяти происходят у него в деструкторе.

В C++ вообще стоит избегать ручного управления памятью, вместо этого необходимо использовать принцип RAII, в частности - умные указатели (`unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr`).

Высокую нагрузку на CPU вызывает бесконечный цикл. Кроме того, чтобы избежать копирования аргументов функций, рекомендуется передавать константные ссылками (`const std::vector<std::wstring> &exceptions`) и при необходимости использовать перемещение.

Comment: Т.е. вероятнее всего я забыл где-то написать delete?

Comment: @Mournehowl, вероятнее всего. Если в `word` у вас есть сырой указатель на буфер с данными (`T*`), то попробуйте заменить его на `std::unique_prt<T>`. Но все равно это сейчас гадание на кофейной гуще, будет лучше, если вы добавите в вопрос листинги `word` и `generator`

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, что такое листинг? Я новичок.

Comment: @Mournehowl, исходники, в данном случае интересует объявление типа `word` и имплементация `generator`.

Comment: Ещё раз извиняюсь, но я не знаю что такое имплементация. Если это просто код класса generator, то я не смогу его здесь вставить, там 1500 строк. Или вы про хэдер generator'а?

Comment: `this->word_data = new std::wstring[2]
{ L"", L"" };
this->seed = new int;`

Comment: @Mournehowl, тела методов (их обычно помещают в *.cpp - файлы, а в хэдерах - внешние объявления). Вам необходимо из этих 1500 строк выкинуть все лишнее, получив >50, где происходит выделение новой памяти и освобождение старой.

Comment: @Mournehowl, Эти `word_data` и `seed` где-то очищаются? Любому явному `new` должен соответствовать свой `delete`, иначе вы перезаписываете новым указателем старый, память, которой он владеет, становится недосигаемой и вечно занятой.

Comment: Попробую кратко описать всю суть:
`generator` хранит в себе два объекта классов `sound_storage` и `data_storage`. Объект класса `data_storage` хранит в себе динамический `int` массив и динамический `std::wstring` массив, во время работы генератора данные в ячейках этих массивов постоянно меняются, при этом никогда не добавляются новые ячейки. `sound_storage` просто хранит двумерный динамический массив со звуками.